# Ability to use Ctrl+z or undo with onEdit trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know this has been asked many times but the answers are not clear or complete
I have certain events happening in my worksheet upon edit and this doest not allow me to use ctrl+z or undo changes.

The events are-
Hide/Unhide sheets, rows and columns.
Toggle a cell background cell in each sheet.
and capture timestamp upon checking a box

Here is the spreadsheet with the code, please help me how can I have people using this spreadsheet use ctrl+z for undo along with the onEdit events-

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jrkiPIIHuZFaKOMOvc0gEH89a39LINBPcHHCoqDOV3s/edit#gid=0

Complete code used in above spreadsheet-

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ccc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ccc.getActiveSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() === "Summary") {
    var tab1 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab1");
    var tab2 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab2");
    var tab3 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab3");
    var tab4 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab4");
    
    var [cella, cellb, cellc, celld] = sheet.getRange("B5:B8").getValues().flat();
    
    if (cella == "Yes") { tab1.showSheet(); } else { tab1.hideSheet(); }
    if (cellb == "Yes") { tab2.showSheet(); } else { tab2.hideSheet(); }
    if (cellc == "Yes") { tab3.showSheet(); } else { tab3.hideSheet(); }
    if (celld == "Yes") { tab4.showSheet(); } else { tab4.hideSheet(); }
  } else if (sheet.getName() === "Tab3") {
    var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var email_check1 = sheet.getRange("E23");
    
    if (email_check1.isChecked()) {
      sheet.getRange("F23").setValue(new Date());
      sheet.getRange("G23").setValue(email);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange("F23").clearContent();
      sheet.getRange("G23").clearContent();
    }
  } else if (sheet.getName() === "Tab4") {
    var cellx = sheet.getRange("D13").getValue();
    
    if (cellx == "Service end" || cellx == "") {
      sheet.hideRows(15);
    } else {
      sheet.showRows(15);
    }
  } else if (sheet.getName() === "Tab1") {
    var check = sheet.getRange("J9").getValue();
    
    if (check == "Direct") {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab2").hideRows(34, 8);
    } else if (check == "Partner" || check == "") {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab2").showRows(34, 8);
    }
    
    var dirpar_check = sheet.getRange("J9").getValue();
    
    if (dirpar_check == "Direct") {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab3").hideColumns(18, 9);
    } else {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab3").showColumns(18, 9);
    }
  }
  
  var toggle1 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab1").getRange("G2");
  var toggle2 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab2").getRange("E2");
  var toggle3 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab3").getRange("H2");
  var toggle4 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab4").getRange("G2");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      toggle1.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle2.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle3.setBackground("BLACK");
      toggle4.setBackground("BLACK");
    } 
      else {
        toggle1.setBackground("WHITE");
        toggle2.setBackground("WHITE");
        toggle3.setBackground("WHITE");
        toggle4.setBackground("WHITE");
      }
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
    Utilities.sleep(200); 
  }

}
```

please help!

Comment: @thank you Tanaike - San, I have onEdit trigger code in the spreadsheet linked above performing different outputs when edit is made in the sheet. Now the code is working as expected but user cannot do undo as undo is also acting as trigger. I want the user to be able to use the edit trigger also and use undo also to work

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `when edit is made in the sheet`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: So when a user selects a particular thing from a drop down in tab1 then fixed columns and fixed rows of tab2 and tab3 are hidden. Another example is that when in a drop-down in summaty tab or sheet is selected then particular sheets get hidden. So these use cases is that the script does when such edits are made of changing or selecting values from drop-downs. I have updated the question with code I have used in the spreadsheet attached

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could find a solution or a workaround, I would like to post it.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike -san, the onEdit trigger steals away the functionality of users to perform undo operation as the undo itself acts as a trigger for onEdit, Google sheets should have/build something in place to fix that. Thanks again for looking into it. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to test your script, can I use your provided Spreadsheet? Unfortunately, I cannot still open your provided Spreadsheet. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike - san, I am really sorry, I updated the access of the sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet and your showing script, I confirmed that the reason for your current issue is due to `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {,,,}` and especially `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. When this is run, it seems that `ctrl+z` cannot be used. So, how about removing the script of `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {,,,}` from your showing script? But, I'm not sure whether this is your expected result. So I posted it as a comment.

Comment: yes @Tanaike - san, I can remove the whole code of that for loop ```for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {,,,}```. I will comment it out and try out if undo works

Comment: @Tanaike - San, I did try to comment out the for loop ```for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {,,,}```along with the ```SpreadsheetApp.flush()``` but ```ctrl+z``` for undo works but on the ```3rd``` time of pressing ```ctrl+z``` continuously, is this something expected?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your issue was resolved. About `but on the 3rd time of pressing ctrl+z continuously, is this something expected?`, unfortuntely, I cannot understand your situation. But, in this case, `ctrl+z` undo the actions of the script. So, it is considered that 3 actions were included in the script. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue. Of course, I can also post it.

Comment: You can post the answer, you post it very well and well formatted and organized. Thank you so much @Tanaike - san!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I posted an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {,,,}` and especially `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`. When `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is used, it seems that `ctrl+z` cannot be used. Because when only `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is removed, `ctrl+z` can be used.

In your script, when `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is removed, `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {,,,}` cannot be used. So, in this modification, `for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {,,,}` and the related script of this is removed as follows. From your reply comment, I understood that you can do this modification.

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ccc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ccc.getActiveSheet();

  if (sheet.getName() === "Summary") {
    var tab1 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab1");
    var tab2 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab2");
    var tab3 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab3");
    var tab4 = ccc.getSheetByName("Tab4");

    var [cella, cellb, cellc, celld] = sheet.getRange("B5:B8").getValues().flat();

    if (cella == "Yes") { tab1.showSheet(); } else { tab1.hideSheet(); }
    if (cellb == "Yes") { tab2.showSheet(); } else { tab2.hideSheet(); }
    if (cellc == "Yes") { tab3.showSheet(); } else { tab3.hideSheet(); }
    if (celld == "Yes") { tab4.showSheet(); } else { tab4.hideSheet(); }
  } else if (sheet.getName() === "Tab3") {
    var email = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
    var email_check1 = sheet.getRange("E23");

    if (email_check1.isChecked()) {
      sheet.getRange("F23").setValue(new Date());
      sheet.getRange("G23").setValue(email);
    } else {
      sheet.getRange("F23").clearContent();
      sheet.getRange("G23").clearContent();
    }
  } else if (sheet.getName() === "Tab4") {
    var cellx = sheet.getRange("D13").getValue();

    if (cellx == "Service end" || cellx == "") {
      sheet.hideRows(15);
    } else {
      sheet.showRows(15);
    }
  } else if (sheet.getName() === "Tab1") {
    var check = sheet.getRange("J9").getValue();

    if (check == "Direct") {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab2").hideRows(34, 8);
    } else if (check == "Partner" || check == "") {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab2").showRows(34, 8);
    }

    var dirpar_check = sheet.getRange("J9").getValue();

    if (dirpar_check == "Direct") {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab3").hideColumns(18, 9);
    } else {
      ccc.getSheetByName("Tab3").showColumns(18, 9);
    }
  }
}
```

- From your script, I guessed that you might want to directly run the script. So, in this modification, I followed your direction that the event object is not used.

#### Note:

- About `but on the 3rd time of pressing ctrl+z continuously, is this something expected?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. But, in this case, `ctrl+z` undo the actions of the script. So, it is considered that 3 actions were included in the script.
- For example, using the above-modified script, when the dropdown list of "B5" of "Summary" sheet is changed from "Yes" to "No" under both the values of "B5:B8" are "Yes" and all sheets are shown, "Tab1" sheet is hidden. And, under this situation, when `ctrl+z` is used one time, "Tab1" sheet is shown. And, when `ctrl+z` is used one more time, the value of "B5" is changed from "No" to "Yes". In this case, 2 steps are used.